# How to change SlotFilling and prompt question from Required parameters throughout backend

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Good morning People, thanks in advance for your time, I have some questions regarding parameters, prompts and intervention from the webhook.

1- Do you know in any way to control from webhook the prompt that is made to the user when a parameter is required?

2- Do you know if there is a way to manipulate these required parameters from the backend at your convenience?

3- I was checking the option of webhook call for slot filling. Has any of you used it? The truth is I am testing it and I would like in-depth on how it works or how it works at the backend level.

If you need help with Db connections, Api Queries, Contexts, Events and others on the backend side, I can help you with that.

Avatar de usuario
nivel 2
Brilliant_Guess3494
PO
·
1d
Hmmm, Let say that my intent is requiring 3 parameters to complete a booking.

The first parameter is Date, depending of what the user says, the prompt of the second parameter can change drastically.

Do you know if that's available? Changing the data when prompts are asked? And also change that prompt structure?

Just imagine we have a multilingual bot, from my backend I got the language that the user speaks so I show different information depending of the language.

As we know, prompts just have one or more possibles options. If I put all in English or mixed with other languages? Do you know what can I do to change the prompt text from the backend?

Comment: For questions 1 and 2, what do you mean by control from webhook? Do you mean how can you get the values via code? It might also be better if you create a separate question for the last part where you are asking about prompts and different languages since there are already a lot of questions in a single post.

Comment: @RiccoD I just want to change the prompt message from my webhook. Is there any way to do it? I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: If you are pertaining to changing/controlling the response via webhook you use `agent.add('your response here')` see [reference](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js#L245). But if you are pertaining to something else, could you elaborate more on your question?

Comment: @RiccoD I Can handle the message that is outputted but I mean changing the promp text when a parameter is required.

Comment: This answer might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/56275602/14733669

Comment: Thanks @Ricco D let me check if that works

Comment: @RiccoD Thanks for the help. It worked. If you have questions related to Df feel free to ask me.